# pandas: how to read file with divided rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I want to read a `dat` file into `pandas` (I'm using `read_table()`), in the file each row of observation is divided into multiple rows like this:

```
var1 var2 var3
var4 var5 var6
1    2    3
4    5    6
1    2    3
4    5    6
1    2    3
4    5    6
```

in this case, each observation is divided into two rows.

Comment: Does it have to be during read in? Can you just slice it like `pdf[::2]`?

Comment: Didn't get around to see this yesterday.. It's a very good idea! I never thought about it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter `skiprows` and `header` in function [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""var1 var2 var3
var4 var5 var6
1    2    3
4    5    6
1    2    3
4    5    6
1    2    3
4    5    6"""
```

```
print range(0, 10)[1::2]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                  sep='\s+', 
                  header=0, 
                  index_col=None, 
                  skiprows=(range(0, 10)[1::2]))
print df1
   var1  var2  var3
0     1     2     3
1     1     2     3
2     1     2     3

print range(2, 10)[::2]
[2, 4, 6, 8]

#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                  sep='\s+', 
                  header=1, 
                  index_col=None, 
                  skiprows=(range(2, 10)[::2]))
print df2
   var4  var5  var6
0     4     5     6
1     4     5     6
2     4     5     6
```

Or you can use postprocessing (as [`Paul`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098297/pandas-how-to-read-file-with-divided-rows/35104546#comment57918212_35098297) suggested) with `header=[0,1]` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and function `droplevel`. Last you can [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""var1 var2 var3
var4 var5 var6
1    2    3
4    5    6
1    2    3
4    5    6
1    2    3
4    5    6"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), 
                  sep='\s+', 
                  header=[0,1])
print df      
  var1 var2 var3
  var4 var5 var6
0    1    2    3
1    4    5    6
2    1    2    3
3    4    5    6
4    1    2    3
5    4    5    6
```

```
df1 = df[::2] 
df1.columns=df.columns.droplevel(1)
print df1.reset_index(drop=True) 
   var1  var2  var3
0     1     2     3
1     1     2     3
2     1     2     3


df1 = df[1::2] 
df1.columns=df.columns.droplevel(0)
print df1.reset_index(drop=True) 
   var4  var5  var6
0     4     5     6
1     4     5     6
2     4     5     6
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've managed to read the data correctly. One question though: how do you decide to use `range(10)`, what if you don't know how many rows are in the file? Right now I just use an arbitrary number.

Comment: Yes, good question. But I think It is not problem change it to `range(10000000)`. This depends of number of rows, you try to estimate it and rather this number multiple by `100`. :)

Comment: I'm not so lucky with the second approach, I guess it's because my data isn't exactly like what I have given in this post,  and the number of columns in each row are not the same., it's more like `var1`  `var2` in the first row, `var3` in the second row, and I got a "list index out of range" error. But I guess I should save it for another question..